# find character in array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method findChar(). This method takes a character and an array of strings as parameters and it prints all the words in the array which contain the specified parameter character.
for example

```
Test                                 Result
String[] words = {"caravan", "car", "van", "bike", "scooter", "vehicle", "bicycle"};

findChar('v', words);  Words containing the letter v : caravan van vehicle
findChar('i', words);  Words containing the letter i : bike vehicle bicycle
```

I got something like this at the moment it's a rough idea but not 100% sure as I'm still a week into learning java so please go easy.

```
   public static void findChar(Char character, String word) {
   for(String word:words) {
            // Check if it contains the character
            if (word.contains(Character.toString(character))) {
                wordsContainingCharacter.add(word);
            }

    if(.....size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Words containing the letter " + character + " : " + ....);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Character is not in any word");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: Your solution looks fine.are you facing any issue?

Comment: This code is quiet good and it's the way you are supposed to write it, what's the point ?

Comment: You don't seem to know what problem you have, or even *if* you have a problem to be solved.

Comment: The method `findChar(Char character, String word)` signature is wrong, it should be `findChar(Char character, String[] words)`

Comment: Your method does not take an array, it takes a single String as parameter.

Comment: problem is i dont know what to add in the if statements and whether they are right or not ive just provided a small template just to see im on the right track

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I need to take out wordsContainingCharacter as well because it doesnt make sense. But like what do i add in my if statements so it all jells together and actually works haha

Comment: @ross.c you use the variable `word` inside the for loop too, that is very bad. Even if is working now, it's just a matter of small changes and it doesn't. And when you look why it never give you a fast answer.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini what would be your way of solving it ? so its efficient ?

Comment: The answer you flagged has the correct signature and the solution to my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
public static void findChar(char character, String words[]) {
    //ArrayList for putting the matched words
    ArrayList<String> wordsContainingCharacter = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String word : words) {
        // Check if it contains the character
        if (word.contains(Character.toString(character))) {
            wordsContainingCharacter.add(word);
        }

    }
    //2.check is to be put after the loop
    if (wordsContainingCharacter.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Words containing the letter " + character
                + " : " + wordsContainingCharacter);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Character is not in any word");
    }
}
```

Logic without using the ArrayList

```
    StringBuilder stringOfWords=new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        // Check if it contains the character
        if (word.contains(Character.toString(character))) {
            stringOfWords.append(word+" ");
        }

    }
    //2.check is to be put after the loop
    if (stringOfWords.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Words containing the letter " + character
                + " : " + stringOfWords);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Character is not in any word");
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to do without using ArrayList<string> I havn't learnt that before

Comment: Yes you can use simple String

Comment: how would you do that ?

Comment: @Logesh im getting this error >>> Main.java:4: illegal start of type
for (String word : words) {

Comment: @ross.c you need to correct the method parameter types

Comment: I get an error when I put this code into Eclipse gives me an error regarding StringBuilder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118594/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-ross-c).